# can I use Kendo UI Grid with Nuget package Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core?

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, reference, kendo-grid, nuget-package

I am running into a strange issue. I built an ASP.net Razor project with a Kendo UI Grid. When I first built it, I made a direct reference to the Kendo.Mvc.dll, and all was good. But I need it to be referenced by a NuGet package. However, when I switch the reference, it no longer recognizes `Html.Kendo().Grid`. I have tried moving the namespace reference from the Views/Web.config to the main web.config as well, but no luck. The error message I get is:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Kendo' and no extension method 'Kendo' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is it possible that something in the larger NuGet Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core package is overriding something in the base Kendo.Mvc.dll? Or does my namespace need to be moved somewhere else? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo UI Core does not include certain widgets, the Grid being one of them, nor does it include the server side wrappers so the Razor helpers such as Html.Kendo().Grid will not work. Hence using the Core package available via NuGet cannot be used for what you need. So the simple answer to your question is, unfortunately, no.